# Strange response (about MySQL) for heroku login on windows (closed)

Tags: mysql, batch-file, heroku, cmd, windows-7-x64

I have heroku toolbelt installed on Windows7 (x64 HomeEd). When i'm trying to login to heroku, i recieve strange message about MySQL (though MySQL already works fine with all software installed):

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
(c) Microsoft Corp., 2009. All rights reserved.

C:\windows\system32>heroku login
"MySQL" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
"MySQL" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.

C:\windows\system32>
```

Exactly like shown - two times. As I found, `heroku.bat` does not invoke MySQL at any step. I think that OS runs some script (a kind of autoexec) just before or in parallel with `heroku.bat`, but i can't find the way used to do this. This is confirmed by the fact that when i start the other bat files the same two messages about MySQL appears.
Can you help me find how that strange script is invoked?

---

Detailed research shown that the reason is MySQL component, named "MySQL Fabric 1.5.3 & MySQL Utilities 1.5.3 1.5". During installation MySQL added it's location to Path environment variable. This caused to break Path variable contents with "&" symbol and any invocation of Path variable cause error

Comment: Is MySQL installed on your system?

Comment: Yes. This message appears regardless of weather MySQL service running or not

Comment: The message has nothing to do with the service. It just tells you, that MySQL (means MySQL.exe) was not found. You should check your PATH env variable and add the path to MySQL.exe to it. Which kind of Server are you using? XAMPP?

Comment: The matter is that i don't want that some script tries to run MySQL or whatever else. MySQL already works fine. I just want to find out the way that strange script have been invoked.

Comment: Sorry, but that's nonsense. When you type `heroku login` and the output is *"MySQL" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file* this means that your call somehow involves MySQL.exe. There is no other explanation. Adjusting %PATH% WILL help. If you want to know where MySQL.exe is called, please post the content of the bat file.

Comment: *I think that OS runs some script (a kind of autoexec) just before or in parallel* No, even if the system would do something, it won't appear in your console.

Comment: @RuslanZhomir: Do this: `findstr /I heroku.bat "mysql"`...

Comment: thanks to everyone. The reason is explained now in question body

Answer (score 0):

It seems that at some point a script tries to call `MySQL.exe` and this file can't be found. To solve this problem you should add the Directory containing MySQL.exe to `%PATH%`. First make sure MySQL.exe is located on your system. If you are not sure where it is, start CMD, go to your root directory (`CD \`) end enter `dir /S MySQL.exe`. This will search your drive for the file and show you the path, where it can be found. Save the path somewhere.

Now that you know where the file is is, you have to add it's location to %PATH%. To do so enter `setx PATH "<NEWPATH>;%path%;"` where  is the path to the directory containing MySQL.EXE. Dont forget `;%path%;`, this is very important. If you don't put it there it wil mess up your %PATH%.

Close the console, open a new one and type `heroku login`. This should fix the problem.

Now if you are not interested in fixing the error and just want to know where it comes from, you should post the code of the batch file that is executed by calling `heroku login`.

Comment: thanks to everyone. The reason is explained now in question body

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;` from your path (It is breaking things up, it gets added during MySQL installation)and add the MySQL bin path. For me it is `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin`